# Alternative algebra with division is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, nonassociative-algebras, jordan-algebras

In the book Rings that are Nearly Associative, has the follow definitions:

$1)$ An algebra $A$ is called an $\textit{algebra with division}$ if, for any elements $a, b \in A$, with $a \neq 0$, each of the equations is solveble in $A$:

$$ax=b \qquad ya=b$$

$2)$ If each of this equations has one and only one solution, and $A$ has an identity element, then $A$ is called a $\textit{division ring}$.

I want to prove that every alternative algebra with division is a division ring.

My attempt:

Let $x_1,x_2$ solutions of $ax=b$, then $ax_1=b$ and $ax_2=b$

$ax_1-ax_2=0 \Rightarrow a(x_1 - x_2)=0$

$a(a(x_1-x_2))=a \cdot 0 \Rightarrow a^2(x_1-x_2)=0$

By the left Moufang identity, we have $a^n(x_1-x_2) = 0$, for all $n\geq 3$.

Since $a \neq 0 $, then $x_1-x_2=0$, therefore $x_1=x_2$

The same for $ya=b$.

My attempt is correct?, something is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You can only do the step $a(x_1-x_2) = 0 \Rightarrow x_1 -x_2 = 0$ if all elements of $A$ are left cancellative, or for instance if $A$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @SeraPhim How can I prove this exercise?